# Node JS Express is not defined when I try to serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to serve static content for the app from the "www" directory in the application directory.

my folders look like this:

```
    -www
    --node_modules
    --js
    --index.js
    --index.html
    --package.json
```

I want to use the main.js file that is inside the js folder but when I try to use the

```
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

in the index.html, my console give me a GET error and 404 file not found.

My code looks something like this:

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
```

when I try to run the server I get the error:

```
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www');
    ReferenceError: express is not defined
```

Can someone give me a hint of why this is happening?

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to import express.

You also should move your non static files outside "www" since that's the path you want for the "static files".

```
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var app = express();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);

 var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www');


 app.use(express.static(publicPath));
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile('index.html', {root: publicPath});
 });
```

Comment: Well that helped because at least I'm not getting the express is not defined Error when I try to run the server anymore, BUT, I'm stil getting the error in the console of 404 file not found. My main.js file is not being recognized and I don't know why...

Comment: stil didn't work. tried to use the example you posted but always getting the 404 error

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you haven't declared any variable named as express. Without variable named as express how you can call it's variables/functions/keys.

To use express./anything/ you have to declare **express** variable in your code. that can be done via

```
var express = require('express');
```

Answer (score 0):

With Webstorm, it didn't work if I used :

`const  express = require('express');`

But work with :
`var express = require('express');`

Maybe it's related to Webstorm, maybe it's not a "good" answer, but for me it solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your answer says express is not defined, then in your cmd or bash terminal,
use the following command:-

```
$ npm install express
```

After the install successfully completes, require the express module using the following:-

```
const express=require('express');
```

run your code. Remember to try it first in
a localhost server. Add a port listener to ur code and try it out.